# AdjustPan with EditText at Bottom of Layout Causes SoftKeyboard to Slightly Obscure EditText View

Tags: android, android-layout

Been looking through various threads to figure this out but I'm still stumped. When I apply "adjustPan" to an activity with an EditText at the bottom, the UI is pushed up correctly but the Edit Text is slightly obscured by the keyboard at the bottom. After closer inspection I noticed it obscures just under the actual text in the edit text so that I can see the full view when I add a new line. It's as if the android mark for what is the bottom of the edit text view is actually the bottom of the last line of text in the edit text rather than the full container. To this end I'm losing a few pixels at the bottom. Would appreciate any thoughts on the matter! Is it a bug of some description perhaps? Been driving me crazy!

Also of note, the workaround of wrapping everything in a scrollView and using adjustResize instead is unfortunately not an option in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: add padding to `EditText`. It will give some space below the edittext

Comment: Thanks for the idea, certainly changes the bottom line the osk get's aligned to but it's breaking the layout a little bit unfortunately...

Comment: @GarryMcKee any solution bro?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` into the activity section of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity>
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
</activity>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix it either, the layout itself isn't resizable.