# adjustPan cuts off bottom of EditText

Tags: android

It appears that `adjustPan` is actually panning on the baseline of my `EditText` rather than the actual edge of the view.

[image: Bottom edge covered]

I've been searching for a way to fix this, but I just haven't been able to find anything.

Activity code (kotlin):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    window.setSoftInputMode(SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
}
```

Layout xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.foo.testbed.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
    android:hint="Message"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/myButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Send"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/myEditText" />
```

I have attempted solutions from the following questions to no avail:

- [adjustPan not preventing keyboard from covering EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)
- [AdjustPan with EditText at Bottom of Layout Causes SoftKeyboard to Slightly Obscure EditText View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435535/adjustpan-with-edittext-at-bottom-of-layout-causes-softkeyboard-to-slightly-obsc)

Comment: AdjustPan only promises the cursor will be in view, not the entire edit text.  There is no fix to this, its working as intended and there is no way to change how it works.

Comment: @nukeforum found anything?

Comment: @iCantC One of the more common answers can be found https://www.davidwparker.com/2011/08/25/android-fixing-window-resize-and-scrolling/ or https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521781. Essentially, wrapping your layout to be scrollable allows the layout to adjust just slightly to display correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to set a top&bot paddings

My example with editText:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/editText_new_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_editbox_height"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/login_edit_box_pass_padding_right"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/edit_box_padding"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
```

[image]

with paddings 12:

[image]

and naked paddings:

[image]

Comment: It's not a perfect solution, but it definitely fixed my problem. Thank you!